# Save latitude/longitude into variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use Location Manager to get my current location. Next I want calculate distance of two points.

Befor onCreate:

```
double clientLatitude, clientLongitude;
TextView v1,v2,v3;
```

In onCreate():

```
    v1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    v2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    v3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            2000, 1, (LocationListener) this);
```

In my onLocationChanged(), onProviderDisabled(), onProviderEnabled() and onStatusChanged() methods:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String msg = "New Latitude: " + location.getLatitude()
            + "New Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
    clientLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    clientLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps OFF!! ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps ON!! ",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

afterConnect()

```
                float distance=0;
                Location crntLocation=new Location("crntlocation");
                crntLocation.setLatitude(clientLatitude);
                crntLocation.setLongitude(clientLongitude);

                Location newLocation=new Location("newlocation");
                newLocation.setLatitude(eventLatitudeS);
                newLocation.setLongitude(eventLongitudeS);

                distance =crntLocation.distanceTo(newLocation) / 1000;

                v1.setText(String.valueOf(clientLongitude));
                v2.setText(String.valueOf(clientLatitude));
                v3.setText(String.valueOf(distance));
```

I declared variables clientLatitude and clientLongitude befor onCreate() method as global vars. When I want to toast current Lat/Lng everything is ok. But when I want to save Lat/Lng into clientLatitude and clientLongitude and later show it e.g. in textView, I always get "0".

Can you tell me reason of this pleas?

Comment: Show all the relevant code

Comment: Please show all the code

Comment: Added all relevant code. :)

Comment: And how are you saving it?